# Accessing external XML files as variables in a PSQL script (sourced from a bash script)

Tags: xml, bash, postgresql, xpath, psql

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007884/import-xml-files-to-postgresql/49950384#49950384), I am having trouble using a PostgreSQL variables in a *.sql script:

- I want to iterate over a number of XML data files, using a BASH script
- the BASH script assigns XML file names to a variable, that is passed to SQL script
- the SQL script, called by that BASH script, loads those data into PostgreSQL

If I source the XML files directly, there is no problem; however, I cannot access that variable, in my SQL script:

In my SQL script (`hmdb.sql`) I can access the PSQL variable `:bash_var` (passed from the BASH script):

```
\echo '\nEXTERNAL VARIABLE (= "datafile", HERE):' :bash_var '\n'
```

and/or directly reference the XML file,

```
datafile text := 'hmdb/hmdb.xml';
```

but not as a variable:

```
datafile text := 'bash_var';
```

---

**hmdb.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA_DIR=data/

for file in $DATA_DIR/*.xml
  do
    bash_var=$(echo ${file##*/})
    echo $bash_var
    psql -d hmdb -v bash_var=$bash_var -f hmdb.sql
done
```

Comment: I deal daily with tons of XML files and I always found that approach easy to implement and to maintain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862106/importing-an-xml-schema-into-postgres-to-automatically-create-a-table-and-then-p/49863444#49863444 doing so you simplify a lot your data import.

Comment: @JimJones: thank you; funny timing, eh? Mentioned in your answer (other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862106/importing-an-xml-schema-into-postgres-to-automatically-create-a-table-and-then-p/49863444#49863444)), I am also using `xml_split` as my file is huge (3.4 GB), and I was getting OOM issues.  I'll post back here once I work through this.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is my solution.

I post a more detailed answer on my [Persagen.com blog](http://persagen.com/2018/05/03/xml-xpath_bash.html).

Basically, I decided to abrogate the `DO $$DECLARE ...` approach (described in [SO 49950384](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007884/import-xml-files-to-postgresql/49950384#49950384)) in favor of the simplified approach, below.

I am then able to access the BASH / PSQL shared variable, `:bash_var`, thusly:

```
xpath('//metabolite', XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT convert_from(pg_read_binary_file(:'bash_var'))))
```

Here is a sample SQL script, illustrating that usage:

**hmdb.sql**

```
\c hmdb

CREATE TABLE hmdb_identifiers (
  id SERIAL,
  accession VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
  cas_number VARCHAR(12),
  pubchem_cid INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (accession)
);

\echo '\n[hmdb.sql] bash_var:' :bash_var '\n'

-- UPDATE (2019-05-15): SEE MY COMMENTS BELOW RE: TEMP TABLE!
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table AS 
SELECT 
  (xpath('//accession/text()', x))[1]::text::varchar(15) AS accession
  ,(xpath('//name/text()', x))[1]::text::varchar(300) AS name 
  ,(xpath('//cas_registry_number/text()', x))[1]::text::varchar(12) AS cas_number 
  ,(xpath('//pubchem_compound_id/text()', x))[1]::text::int AS pubchem_cid 
-- FROM unnest(xpath('//metabolite', XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT convert_from(pg_read_binary_file('hmdb/hmdb.xml'), 'UTF8')))) x
FROM unnest(xpath('//metabolite', XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT convert_from(pg_read_binary_file(:'bash_var'), 'UTF8')))) x
;

INSERT INTO hmdb_identifiers (accession, name, cas_number, pubchem_cid)
  SELECT lower(accession), lower(name), lower(cas_number), pubchem_cid FROM tmp_table;

DROP TABLE tmp_table;
```

---

**SQL script notes:**

- In the xpath statements I recast the `::text` (e.g.: `::text::varchar(15)`) per the Postgres table schema.
- More significantly, if I did **not** recast the datatypes in the xpath statement and a field entry (e.g. `name` length) exceeded the SQL `varchar(300)` length limit, those data threw a PSQL error and the table did not update (i.e. a blank table results).

I uploaded the XML data files used in this answer at this Gist

https://gist.github.com/victoriastuart/d1b1959bd31e4de5ed951ff4fe3c3184

Direct links:

- [hmdb_metabolites_5000-01.xml](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/victoriastuart/d1b1959bd31e4de5ed951ff4fe3c3184/raw/ccde8473a23e40e5208926e03c7ae89455a8b2b2/hmdb_metabolites_5000-01.xml)
- [hmdb_metabolites_5000-02.xml](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/victoriastuart/d1b1959bd31e4de5ed951ff4fe3c3184/raw/ccde8473a23e40e5208926e03c7ae89455a8b2b2/hmdb_metabolites_5000-02.xml)
- [hmdb_metabolites_5000-03.xml](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/victoriastuart/d1b1959bd31e4de5ed951ff4fe3c3184/raw/ccde8473a23e40e5208926e03c7ae89455a8b2b2/hmdb_metabolites_5000-03.xml)
- Source: [HMDB.ca](http://www.hmdb.ca/)

  - [Citation](http://www.hmdb.ca/about#cite)

---

**UPDATE (2019-05-15)**

In follow-on work, detailed in my research blog post [Exporting Plain Text to PostgreSQL](https://persagen.com/2019/05/14/plaintext2postgres.html), I directly load XML data into PostgreSQL, rather than using temp tables.

**TL/DR.** In that project, I observed the following improvements.

```
Parameter | Temp Tables  | Direct Import | Reduction
    Time: | 1048 min     | 1.75 min      | 599x
   Space: | 252,000 MB   | 18 MB         | 14,000x
```